# Memory map and Framebuffer after using ExitBootServices

Tags: 64-bit, boot, osdev

I guess the question is pretty straight forward itself.
**Is there any way of detecting the memory (or getting he memory map) and framebuffer (or Graphics Output Protocol) after using `ExitBootServices` in UEFI in 64-bit mode? If so then how and is there any documentation?**
I know that after using `ExitBootServices`, you the the sole owner of the entire machine.
There are many ways of getting the memory map but they all take help of the bootloader. I want to get the memory map directly from the kernel. Many websites such as OSDev and github sources use bootloaders to get the memory map and framebuffer.
After using `ExitBootServices`, I'm left in 64-bit mode and the only page on OSDev wiki about getting the memory map works on 32-bit architecture.
I have no language preferences, it may be in C, assembly or whatever and please don't say that it's useless or complicated or difficult to do. I just want an answer.

Comment: Anyone with any solution?

Comment: You can't. After exiting boot services you are left having to do a full scan of memory which is hard to do and impractical. Maybe you can get some information from ACPI tables.

Answer (score 1):

First, (Probably in (U)EFI) U cannot call boot services which is the only way to get what you want, you can get the memory map & Frame Buffer before ExitBootServices() and pass them to the kernel, you're lucky cause I'm not always on this platform, I've a Hybrid Boot Mechanism with LEGACY BIOS & UEFI Support, and here is an example of how to do that (I'm working on EDK2 Which is the Official Implementation of EFI)

**This is how you get the frame buffer from G.O.P ( UGA documentation is removed ):**

```
FRAME_BUFFER_DESCRIPTOR* GraphicsOutputProtocolInitialize(){

// First, we need to query the firmware of all G.O.P Protocol Instances
// (Each instance may represent a GPU or a monitor, GOP features multiple-screens

// U have asked for a simple implementation so we will use only 1 frame buffer

 EFI_STATUS status = 0;

EFI_HANDLE* HandleBuffer = NULL;
UINTN NumProtocolHandles = 0;

if(EFI_ERROR(gBS->LocateHandleBuffer(
    ByProtocol, &gEfiGraphicsOutputProtocolGuid, NULL,
    &NumProtocolHandles, &HandleBuffer
)) || !NumProtocolHandles) return NULL;

// Then u need to create a structure that you can pass to the kernel containing information about frame buffers

FRAME_BUFFER_DESCRIPTOR* FrameBuffer = NULL;
if(EFI_ERROR(gBS->AllocatePool(
    EfiLoaderData, sizeof(FRAME_BUFFER_DESCRIPTOR), (void**)&FrameBuffer
))) ALLOCATION_PROBLEM;

ZeroMemory((void*)FrameBuffer, sizeof(FRAME_BUFFER_DESCRIPTOR));

    EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_PROTOCOL* gop = NULL;
    status = gBS->OpenProtocol(
        HandleBuffer[0], // Get first Graphics Output Protocol Instance
        &gEfiGraphicsOutputProtocolGuid,
        (void**)&gop,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        EFI_OPEN_PROTOCOL_GET_PROTOCOL
    );
    if(EFI_ERROR(status) || !gop)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    EFI_GRAPHICS_OUTPUT_MODE_INFORMATION* ginfo = NULL;
    UINTN info_size = 0;

    // if mode is not yet set by firmware, then set first mode
    if(status == EFI_NOT_STARTED || !gop->Mode){
        
        status = gop->SetMode(gop, 0);
        if(EFI_ERROR(status) || !gop->Mode->Mode)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // Now we will ask firmware for the current Video Mode
    
    status = gop->QueryMode(gop, gop->Mode->Mode, &info_size, &ginfo);
    
   
    if(status != EFI_SUCCESS || !ginfo){
        return NULL;
    }
    
    // You can also list availaible video modes
   for(UINTN i = 0;i<gop->Mode->MaxMode;i++) {
      status = gop->QueryMode(gop, i, &info_size, &ginfo);
    
   
    if(status != EFI_SUCCESS || !ginfo){
        return NULL;
    }

    // To set the mode :
    status = gop->SetMode(gop, i);
    if(EFI_ERROR(status))
    {
        return NULL;
    }
   }

    
    FrameBuffer->FrameBufferSize = gop->Mode->FrameBufferSize;
    FrameBuffer->HorizontalResolution = gop->Mode->Info->HorizontalResolution;
    FrameBuffer->VerticalResolution = gop->Mode->Info->VerticalResolution;
    FrameBuffer->FrameBufferBase = (char*)gop->Mode->FrameBufferBase;


    ZeroMemory((void*)FrameBuffer, sizeof(FRAME_BUFFER_DESCRIPTOR));

}




 return FrameBuffer;

 }
```

**This is how you get the memory map :**

- On the first Call you will get the size of the memory map (Status must be EFI_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL)
- Then you add 2 * descriptor size coz there is always 2 additional entries, then you allocate buffer for memory map
- On the second call, you will get the actual memory map (Status must be EFI_SUCCESS)

Then u can list memory map entries normally

**This is how u make a call to GetMemoryMap() :**

```
EFI_MEMORY_DESCRIPTOR* memory_map = NULL;
UINTN map_size = 0, map_key = 0, descriptor_size = 0;



// Must return EFI_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL on First Call 
// map_size will contain buffer size needed
EFI_STATUS s = SystemTable->BootServices->GetMemoryMap(&map_size,memory_map,&map_key,&descriptor_size,&descriptor_version);
map_size+=2*descriptor_size; // this padding must be added since there is 2 additionnal entries
```

However, u can always ask for a code sample, the previous code of (G.O.P) is just copy-pasted and modified to make it a little bit easier to understand, it is not compiled so it may contain some faults.

Comment: Does this answer the question? A comment in the question by @user123 answered the question properly btw...

Comment: @0xdead I have no enough reputations to answer I'm a new user.